# Laravel 5 Storage::delete() error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to delete a file stored in app_folder/storage/app/images/business/filename_here.png using the following code:

```
Storage::delete(storage_path('app/images/business/'.$business->logo));
```

The error that I get is the following:

```
FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 381:
File not found at path: home/vagrant/Code/app_folder/storage/app/images/business/1_logo.png
```

The problem is that the path that is displayed is absolutely correct, the filename also. Any ideas ?

Comment: Your path is incorrect: `home/vagrant/Code/app_folder/storage/app/images/business/1_logo.png` is a relative folder, it should be `/home/vagrant/Code/app_folder/storage/app/images/business/1_logo.png` to be correct, the path will be relative to the Laravel (apache?) run dir

Comment: do you have the permission to delete the file, some time your file is just read only, or no permission were assigned, that why it give you error

Comment: Well by doing a var_dump() I found that the path is actually `/home/vagrant/Code/app_folder/storage/app/images/business/1_logo.png`, also I tried with unlink() and it worked using the same path

Comment: My case the file was read only. So you need to add file permission when you upload. https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/issues/240

Comment: I just had a similar issue. try using Storage::delete('images/business/'.$business->logo));